# Using Post for Each API Call , even for get Resource.?

Tags: http, architecture

HY

i was working with backend Architecture using http methods like standards

get for getting resource, 
post for adding some resorce 
put for update and delete for deleting resource.

but someone insisted me to change all methods to post, with this logic that this is not secure way to call get , delete with parameters.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good advice. However, one of the requirements for GET is, it should not change any state. If some change is happenning internally in the logic, POST is the right choice. Similarly PUT has to be idempotent. If your logic is not idempotent, POST should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST is not inherently any more secure than the other HTTP methods.  There may be something in your particular framework that has different authorization paths for GET vs POST.

More likely they just have some historical experience which is no longer relevant.  You really want to stick with the RESTful design as much as you possibly can (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE).  It has real benefits in the long run.